# jQuery: ajax post to external form and redirect to response page on success

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have to post to an external login page through ajax call.

If the credentials are right, how can I redirect to the external response page?

Thanks!

```
  $('.customer-login-form').on('submit', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.valid()) {
      $.ajax('https://google.com/login',
        {
          data: $this.serialize(),
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'script',
          success: function() {
            window.location = 'https://google.com/your-summary';
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.location`

```
document.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025527/jquery-ajax-post-to-external-form-and-redirect-to-response-page-on-success';
```

Comment: Hi I have added a sample response based on your answer. Is it what you mean? I am getting unexpected token in the console though.

Comment: Yes. Better to use `document.location` not `window.location`, but anyway it will redirect user to page you want.

Comment: ooooore ...just realized - may be your are looking on how to get data from external page? not to redirect user to external page?

Comment: you wouldn't probably try to authorize at `google.com` right?

Comment: Redirecting to external page. Google is just a sample website!

Comment: Say we are posting to google/login and the user should be redirected to google/summary if they submit correct credential. Assuming google is the external website I want to post to.

Comment: Do you control the external website? Can you change same-origin policy headers there or create jsonP action response?

Comment: Actually, I just changed the datatype to script and the redirect worked. But the credentials (which was correct) could not be verified when redirecting.

Comment: If you dont control external website and if it doesnt send you headers like `same-origin: "*"` and `allow-credentials: true` then you won't be able to use `ajax` - it's restricted on purpose by `same-origin policy`. Only option you have to do this stuff is to create nginx proxy and proxy such requests through your own domain.